# Value returned from PHP extension function is NULL

Tags: php, php-extension

I've stumbled upon an interesting case while developing an extension for PHP. In the extension code I have:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(foo)
{
   ....
   php_debug_zval_dump(return_value, 1);
}
```

In the PHP code:

```
$v = foo();
debug_zval_dump($v);
```

When running the above, I get:

```
string(19) "Mouse configuration" refcount(1)
NULL refcount(2)
```

What can be the reason that the value isn't passed properly from the extension?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show more of your php function. You're most likely doing something wrong before. Also, why are there three "refcount(x)" in your output? Your snippet explains only two.

Comment: Yes, I was doing something wrong (I've fixed that already). It's strange that `php_debug_zval_dump(return_value, 1)` still printed the correct value, even though it wasn't passed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that strange.

For instance, if you did `return_value = some_string_zval;` you would be changing only the local variable. `php_debug_zval_dump` would work, but it would have no effect outside the function. You have to actively copy the zval, e.g. with:

```
ZVAL_COPY_VALUE(return_value, my_string_zval_p);
zval_copy_ctor(return_value);
```

The only case you could return from an internal function merely copying a pointer instead of copying data was if that function returned by reference. In that case, you're given a `zval**`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a NULL because debug_zval_dump() has a built-in echo feature and you cannot set an echo to a variable.  So your $v = foo() is actually giving you $v = "".  The reason you're getting a refcount of 2 for an empty variable is because of inherent PHP optimization.

Read about that here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php

So to return your value properly you can:

1. Suppress the built-in echo by writing the echo to a buffer
2. Set the buffer result to a variable
3. Run your second debug_zval_dump() on that (not NULL) variable

Here's how it works:

```
function myfunc($foo)
{
  debug_zval_dump($foo, 1);
}
ob_start();
/*
starts the output buffer which will catch all code instead of echoing it to page
*/
myfunc('Mouse configuration');

$v = ob_get_contents();
/*
writes the buffer which contains your f(x) results to a var
*/

ob_end_clean();//clears the buffer

debug_zval_dump($v);//will echo non-null value
```

The code will result with this:

**string(65) "string(19) "Mouse configuration" refcount(3) long(1) refcount(1) " refcount(2)**

I have no idea what this code is meant to do but Good Luck anyways.  :)